# How to determine if JSON object has property, and that if it does is the properties value is greater than 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some returned JSON from an API similar to this:

```
{"amount_to_collect":0,"breakdown":{"city_tax_collectable":0,"city_tax_rate":0,"city_taxable_amount":0,"combined_tax_rate":0,"county_tax_collectable":0,"county_tax_rate":0,"county_taxable_amount":0,"line_items":[{"city_amount":0,"city_tax_rate":0,"city_taxable_amount":0,"combined_tax_rate":0,"county_amount":0,"county_tax_rate":0,"county_taxable_amount":0,"id":"1","special_district_amount":0,"special_district_taxable_amount":0,"special_tax_rate":0,"state_amount":0,"state_sales_tax_rate":0,"state_taxable_amount":0,"tax_collectable":0,"taxable_amount":0}],"special_district_tax_collectable":0,"special_district_taxable_amount":0,"special_tax_rate":0,"state_tax_collectable":0,"state_tax_rate":0,"state_taxable_amount":0,"tax_collectable":0,"taxable_amount":0}}
```

I need to check if the "amount_to_collect" exists, and if it does check if the value is greater than 0, including any cents IE 0.01 should be greater.

I can check if it exists with:

```
if (data.hasOwnProperty("amount_to_collect"))
```

I can check if it is greater than zero with

```
if(data.amount_to_collect == 0) {
    alert('zero');
} else if(data.amount_to_collect > 0) {
    alert('greater')
}
```

but cannot figure out how to check if it exists and if it exists is the value greater than zero. In some cases, it might not be returned and I need to have a case for that.

Comment: It's really easy, just read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) ... You'll find out, that JSON object contains only two methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tax` in your code will only ever contain the boolean result of `hasOwnProperty()`. Given the object in your example that will only ever be `true`, hence you always see the 'greater' output.

To fix this you need to separate the variable containing the result of checking that the property exists from the value of the property itself. Try this:

```js
let data = {
  "amount_to_collect": 0
  // other properties...
}

var propertyExists = data.hasOwnProperty("amount_to_collect");
if (propertyExists && data.amount_to_collect > 0) {
  console.log('greater');
} else {
  console.log('less');
}
```

Comment: Please see updated question. 'amount_to_collect' can be 0, can be greater than zero, or in some cases not even exist in the object

Comment: Your question asks 'cannot figure out how to check if it exists and is greater than zero' - this answers that.